# Подскажите сервис где можно реализовать промежуточный скрипт

Tags: javascript

Суть следующая. Есть сайт построенный на tilda. К сайту подключил CRM и различные платёжки... Для того чтоб общаться с API платёжек нужно отправлять сложные заголовки + BASE AUTH, сервак конструктора сложные заголовки типа Authorization блокирует. Мне необходимо общаться с API мерчантов - для того чтоб подтягивать некоторую инфу на сайт для дальнейшей отправки в CRM, но сделать это я не могу из-за политики безопасности сервака. Подскажите-какие то сервисы,обходные пути. Тоесть, мне надо отправить инфу с сайта конструктора простым запросом на сторонний скрипт, у которого уже нет проблем с CORS, который благополучно отправит запрос с полученой информацией дальше. У кого какие соображения на этот счёт, есть какие-то сервисы для промежуточных скриптов на JS  для реализации моих хотелок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем методом поисков нашел hook.io , сервак на node.js с кучей подключённых модулей.